# Formatting the data to populate google charts

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, google-visualization

I am trying to display Line charts using Google API. For the same I tried to format the data from ASP.net Webmethod like

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static List<object> GetChartData()
 {
        List<object> chartData = new List<object>();

        chartData.Add(new object[]

        {
           "DateTime", "Bugs" 
         });

        chartData.Add(new object[]
                {
                  "2011", "12",
                  "2014","45",
                  "2015","40",
                  "2016","98"
                });

        return chartData;
 }
```

and here is my Client side code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var options = {
            title: 'Bug Tracker'
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetChartData",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($("#chart")[0]);
                chart.draw(data, options);
            },
            failure: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            },
            error: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

On running the above code I am getting an error like `0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Row 0 has 8 columns, but must have 2` What is wrong and how to resolve that ?

Comment: Please wirte that data harcoded in ajax response and put that in fiddle so we can checkout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

any column after the first, should be a number
unless given a specific role, such as `tooltip`

try this...

```
chartData.Add(new object[] {"DateTime", "Bugs"});
chartData.Add(new object[] {"2011", 12});
chartData.Add(new object[] {"2014", 45});
chartData.Add(new object[] {"2015", 40});
chartData.Add(new object[] {"2016", 98});
```

or on the client, adjusting the code in the comment...

```
var charData = r.d;
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
data.addColumn('number', 'Bugs');

for (var i = 0; i < charData.length; i++) {
  data.addRow([charData[i].DateTime, pareseInt(charData[i].Bugs)]);
}
```

**EDIT**

with data as follows...
`[["DateTime","Bugs"],["2011",12],["2014",45],["2015",40],["2016",98]]`

then only need `arrayToDataTable` to create DataTable

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var r = {};

    r.d = [["DateTime","Bugs"],["2011",12],["2014",45],["2015",40],["2016",98]];

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);

    var options = {
      title: "Bug Tracker",
      pointSize: 5
    };

    var lineChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    lineChart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Tried the shared Code adding on C# and here is my client side `
                    var charData = r.d;
                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'Bugs');
                    for (var i in charData) {
                        data.addRow([charData.DateTime[i], ints[charData.Bugs[i]]]);
                    }` but its giving me error as `0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: error is removed but I am not seeing any chart getting rendered. We have not added markup id and type of chart. Do I need to add it at `var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
`

Comment: Added `var options = {
                        title: "Bug Tracker",
                        pointSize: 5
                    };

                    var lineChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                    lineChart.draw(data, options);`. Now getting the chart is Blank..

Comment: Updated the Post with latest rendered Chart pic also. Please help me .Thanks

Comment: This is the Data from Console `[["DateTime","Bugs"],["2011",12],["2011",45],["2011",40],["2011",98]]`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

> "On running the above code I am getting an error like 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Row 0 has 8 columns, but must have 2"  What is wrong and how to resolve that ?

You are adding the entire table and it's reading the number of rows as the number of columns.  It's expecting two columns with 8 rows of data. Break it down to something like this, this is if you are accessing the data from the class.:

Without seeing all your code this is a sample of the type of algorithm you would need:

Create a class for your objects' data:

```
public class MyData{

    public string Year {get; set;}
    public int Bugs {get; set;}

    var bugs = new List<MyData>BugList():
    // add data.
```

Get that data with your ajax to a method that will get the List of data and serialize it into a Json format.

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bugs);
```

You can then access the data from within the javascript. It's important to separate out the chart part of the code from the C# data, for the sake of modularisation. Hence the details for the chart are added where the chart is created.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
data.addColumn('number', 'Bugs');
for (var i in chardata) {
    data.addRow([chardata.Year[i], ints[chardata.Bugs[i]]]);
}
```

As an example try the following:

```
var str = new string[3] {"2011", "2012", "2013"};

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
data.addColumn('number', 'Bugs');
for (var i in str) {
    data.addRow([str[i], ints[i]]);
}
```

Test it on something simple like this, then work on accessing your data through the ajax.

Comment: tried to with the shared code but getting `0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: Saw your example. The issue is with my server side code format. Whatever code I have shared with the Post is the complete . Could you please help me to correct that one.Thanks